# Can I use Cantor's diagonal argument to show $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not countable?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

So the set can be rewritten as:

$$\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}=\{(a,b,c,d,....) : a,b,c,d,... \in (0,1) \}$$

And so we can write those sequences as:

$$111111111...$$
$$010101010...$$

etc.

And then we pick the $1$st number of the first sequence and change it to $0$, we pick the second of the second etc. etc. and so we will end up with a sequence that is not in any of the sequences in the set, and so $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable.

And then a follow up a question. I do not necessarily have to pick the "diagonal" numbers, do I? I can just pick every first number of every sequence and I would still end up with a sequence that is different to every sequence from which it is constructed, correct?

Comment: What does "pick every first number of every sequence" mean?

Comment: @bof I interpreted that as meaning that their new sequence is $(1-S_1(1), 1-S_2(1), 1-S_3(1), . . .)$ - that is, make the $i$th bit of the new sequence different from the first bit of the $i$th sequence.

Comment: As posted answers show, the first answer is "yes". It's standard to think of those sequences of $0$s and $1$s as expressing a number in the unit interval as a binary decimal. That shows $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ counts the real numbers in $[0,1]$. (You have to fuss a little bit with decimals that end with all $1$s.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber correct. sorry for not making it more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes.

The answer to your second question, however, is **no**: in order to conclude that some sequence $D$ is not on your list of sequences $S_1 S_2, . . . $, you need to argue:

> For each $i$, $D$ *disagrees with the $i$th sequence somewhere*: that is, for some $n$, $S_i(n)\not=D(n)$.

(This is just because this is what it means for two sequences to be different! Two sequences are different iff they disagree somewhere; so if I want to conclude that $D\not=S_i$ for any $i$, I have to argue that - for each $i$ - there is some "point of disagreement".)

The diagonal argument picks $n=i$: the $i$th bit of $D$ is different from the $i$th bit of $S_i$, for each $i$. We could pick differently: e.g. make the $i+17$th bit of $D$ different from the $i+17$th bit of $S_i$.

By contrast, what you've described - making the $i$th bit of $D$ different from the $1$st bit of $S_i$ - isn't enough! There's no reason to believe that this actually produces a sequence not on the list.

For a concrete example of how this can go wrong, suppose your list looks like:

- $S_1=0111111111...$
- $S_2=1000000000...$
- $S_2=1100000000...$
- $S_3=1110000000...$
- And so on.

Then if we do the "change the first bit" trick you describe, the sequence we'll produce is $$10000000000...,$$ which *is on the list* as $S_2$.

By contrast, the classically-constructed (anti)diagonal sequence is $$11111111111...,$$ which isn't on the list (we know it can't be $S_i$ since its $i$th bit isn't the $i$th bit of $S_i$). Of course, this sequence is in a sense the "limit" of the list, but that's not relevant - it's not *on the list*.

Comment: I see.. and obviously, in my case, they are not different because the only $n$ that I am picking from original sequences is $1$ and so all the other indices may not and will not be different. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To your first question, yes, you don't have to pick the diagonals, but to your second, no, the new sequence should differ from all those listed in at least one entry.

Answer (score 1):

Associate a sequence $s\in\left\{ 0,\,1\right\}^\mathbb{N}$ with $S_s:=\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}|s_n=1\right\}$. A list $\left( s^j\right) _{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ of such sequences is now associated with $S_{s^j}$ (we use superscripts to number sequences and subscripts to number entries within them). If $\left\{ n\in\mathbb{N}|s^n_n=0\right\}=S_{s^k}$, $s^k_k=0$ iff $k\in S$, i.e. iff $s^k_k=1$.

Depending on how you read this proof by contradiction, you can consider it either the "diagonal argument" on sequences or a special case of the proof of Cantor's theorem (i.e. the result that taking the power set obtains a greater cardinality). Just as one needs to construct a certain set to prove Cantor's theorem, one needs to construct a certain sequence to prove the $s^j$ aren't exhaustive. This relation between subsets and sequences on $\left\{ 0,\,1\right\}$ motivates the description of the proof of Cantor's theorem as a "diagonal argument".